# i'm unable to find out any error in this code but it is showing seg fault, can someone help me?

Tags: segmentation-fault, runtime-error

Node* n1 = head;
Node* n2 = head;
while(true)
{
if(n1->next==NULL&&n2==NULL&&n2->next==NULL)
return 0;
n1 = n1->next;
n2 = n2->next->next;
if(n1==n2)
{
int len =1;
while(n1->next!=n2)
{
n1 = n1->next;
len++;
}
return len;
}
i'm using this to calculate length of loop in linked list and when i submit it on gfg it is showing as seg fault. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
n2 = n2->next->next;
```

After sufficient passes through the outer while loop, `n2` points to the last node in the linked list, thus `n2->next` is `NULL`, and `n2->next->next` attempts to do something that it shouldn't.